# Possible way of using same function on two different divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `addRow()` and `deleteRow()` functions. I'm pasting the function twice for each of my choices (radio & checkbox). Is there any other way to lessen it?

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createElement("input");

  element1.type = "checkbox";
  element1.name = "chkbox[]";
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var element2 = document.createElement("input");
  element2.type = "text";
  element2.name = "txtbox[]";
  cell2.appendChild(element2);

}

function addRow1(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createElement("input");

  element1.type = "radiobtn";
  element1.name = "rdbtn[]";
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var element2 = document.createElement("input");
  element2.type = "text";
  element2.name = "txtbox[]";
  cell2.appendChild(element2);
}
```

Comment: The only difference is the `type` and `name` properties you set, so make them arguments of the single function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addRow(tableID , inputType, inputName) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createElement("input");

  element1.type = inputType;
  element1.name = inputName;
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var element2 = document.createElement("input");
  element2.type = "text";
  element2.name = "txtbox[]";
  cell2.appendChild(element2);

}
addRow(tableID, "checkbox", "chkBox[]"); //or
addRow(tableID, "radiobtn", "rdbtn[]");
```

You have to send your properties to your "addRow" function.

For a closer look read: https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to create the elements something like this:

```js
/** 
 * @param {string} tagName The name of the element to create like "input" or "div"
 * @param {Object<string, string> properties This object can be used to set properties on the 
 *        element like its name or type.
 * @param {Array<HTMLElement> [children=[]] An optional parameter to provided elements to be 
 *        added as children to the created element.
 */          
function createElement(tagName, properties, children = []) {
  // Create the element
  const element = document.createElement(tagName);
  // Get all the properties names of the properties object, iterate over all of them and 
  // set the property in the element with the provided value.
  Object.keys(properties).forEach(key => {
    element[key] = properties[key]
  });
  // Append any childeren that may have been provided.
  children.forEach(child => element.appendChild(child));
  
  // Return the element.
  return element;
}

const myElement = createElement('input', {
  type: 'checkbox',
  name: 'my-checkbox'
});
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```